# Visual Constraints with Hidden Views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, constraints

I'm struggling a bit with visual constraints in my iOS app.

I have four UIViews. One is always the "header" or top view, and the other three take turns being visible below it, as follows:

```
+-------------------+
| HeaderView        |
+-------------------+
| View2|View3|View4 |
+-------------------+
```

Only one of View2, View3, or View4 is visible at a time, and the others are hidden when not in use.

Now, using regular `NSLayoutConstraints`, I'm able to get it working really well:

1. All views have constraints for Leading and Trailing margin to match the host super-view.
2. HeaderView has TopMargin to match host super-view.
3. All views have constraints on their height. HeaderView is 100, and View2, View3, and View4 are 25, 50, and 75 respectively.
4. View2, View3, and View4 all have constraints that set their Top equal to HeaderView Bottom.
5. (I don't care about any bottom bounding for View2, View3, or View4 — their heights are fixed, and empty space below them is managed elsewhere.)

So, I'm trying to convert this to visual constraints. Here's what I have so far for horizontal constraints and it's great:

```
@"H:|-0-[HeaderView]-0-|"
@"H:|-0-[View2]-0-|"
@"H:|-0-[View3]-0-|"
@"H:|-0-[View4]-0-|"
```

Now, vertical constraints are where I get into trouble:

I've tried the following:

```
@"V:|-0-[HeaderView(100)]-0-[View2(25)]-0-[View3(50)]-0-[View4(75)]"
```

And I've also tried splitting that up:

```
@"V:|-0-[HeaderView(100)-0-[View2(25)]"
@"V:|-0-[HeaderView(100)-0-[View2(50)]"
@"V:|-0-[HeaderView(100)-0-[View2(75)]"
```

Now, the problem is that the vertical layout is never correct — almost always, View2, View3, or View4 will lie right on top of HeaderView, not below it.

Any suggestions for how to clean this up and fix my vertical layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 V:[HeaderView(100)]-[View1(25)]
 V:[HeaderView(100)]-[View2(50)]
 V:[HeaderView(100)]-[View3(75)]
```

And make sure that you are properly setting `views` parameter of `constraintsWithVisualFormat` method. It should be `super view` of your `views` on which you are setting constraints or it should be view with whom your constraints are related.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: One more doubt :) Arent you  applying all the 25 30 75 height constraint on sameView View2 when the requirement was to apply it for View1,View2 and View 3 :) I know that was the part of his question but thats wrong isnt it :) The affect is that height of View2 will be 75 where as others height will be implicit so set to 0 :)

Comment: Yeah it was also typo, i have just copy and pasted one line three times in answer from OP and forget to edit!

Comment: This one worked the best for me. Thanks! Pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

MarcWan,

There is nothing wrong in constraint I believe if this is exactly the constraints you have used you missed ']' in all the constraints.

try this,

```
@"V:|-0-[HeaderView(100)]-0-[View2(25)]-0-[View3(50)]-0-[View4(75)]"
```

Comment: @marcwan : Have you written HeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,View2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, View3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and finally View4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Yah, the above answer from @lion totally did the trick. I just want to play around with your answer a bit more and see if I can get it all back into one line again ^_^